# Jquery drop down on click()

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made simpla dropdown menu using jquery that works on hover, so could anyone help me to adjust it so it would work on click and not on hover?
Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hnv2w29a/)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>child 1
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>child 1.1
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>child 1.1.1</li>
          <li>child 1.1.2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>child 1.2
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>child 1.2.1</li>
          <li>child 1.2.2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>child 2
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>child 2.1</li>
      <li>child 2.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.sub-menu {display: none;}
```

**Jquery**

```
$("ul.menu").find('> li').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find('> ul').slideDown();
    },
    function() {
        $(this).find('> ul').hide();
    }
);

$("ul.sub-menu").find('> li').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find('> ul').slideDown();
    },
    function() {
        $(this).find('> ul').hide();
    }
);
```

Comment: You can't click without hovering, so that seems redundant.

Comment: Edited, want to work only on click, and not on hover.Thanks

Comment: research jQuery `.click()` event.

Comment: @user3254754 That's pretty easy...

Comment: If it is easy, please show me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use slideToggle or toggle functions in a click() event handler to achieve your desired result

**Update** you need to stop event bubling in sub menu click event so that it doesnt call click event for menu and slideUp the main menu

```
$("ul.menu").find('> li').click(
    function(e) {

        $(this).find('> ul').slideToggle();


      //  $(this).find('> ul').toggle();
    }
);

$("ul.sub-menu").find('> li').click(
    function(e) { 
        e.stopPropagation()

        $(this).find('> ul').slideToggle();

       // $(this).find('> ul').toggle();
    }
);
```

**Working demo Below:**

```js
$("ul.menu").find('> li').click(
    function() {
        $(this).find('> ul').slideToggle();
  

       // $(this).find('> ul').toggle();
    }
);

$("ul.sub-menu").find('> li').click(
    function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation()
        $(this).find('> ul').slideToggle();
   
       // $(this).find('> ul').toggle();
    }
);
```

```css
.sub-menu {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>child 1
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>child 1.1
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>child 1.1.1</li>
          <li>child 1.1.2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>child 1.2
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>child 1.2.1</li>
          <li>child 1.2.2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>child 2
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>child 2.1</li>
      <li>child 2.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try to click on "child 1" and than on child 1.1. See what happens? Could that be fix too? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Edited, want to work only on click, and not on hover.Thanks

Replace `.hover` with `.click`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the process I would suggest you try.

1. Use the `click` function instead of the `hover` function.
2. Add a hyperlink with `display: block` to the main menu `li` so you can target clicks on the parent `li`. Otherwise, a click inside the sub-menu will hide the sub-menu.
3. Attach an event handler to the document body (`$(document).click(...)`) that will close any open menus.
4. Make sure you call `event.preventDefault` inside your click handlers so a menu click doesn't propagate to the body's click handler.
5. Close any open menus before you open the one the user clicked on.

```js
    $(document).click(
      function onClick_body(event) {
        $("ul.menu > li > ul").hide(); // Clicking outside the menu hides the menu.
      }
    );
    $("ul.menu > li > a").click(
      function onClick_menu(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevents the click from going to the body.
        var $submenu = $(this).sibling("ul"); // Gets the ul next to the hyperlink.
        if (!$submenu.is(":visible")) { // Is this submenu already visible?
          $("ul.menu > li > ul").hide(); // No. Hide other menus.
          $submenu.slideDown(); // Now show this submenu.
        } else
          $submenu.hide(); // Yes. Hide this menu.
      }
    );
```